# Create an array of sentences from a string - Java Velocity Template

Tags: java, html, velocity

I am using velocity templates and need to split the output of a function into an array of sentences:

---

```
$page.getSectionCopy()
```

which outputs:

```
The first sentence. The second sentence. The third sentence. The fourth sentence.The fifth sentence.
```

---

What I would like to achieve is the following:

```
<p>
The first sentence. The second sentence.
</p>
<p>
The third sentence. The fourth sentence. The fifth sentence. 
</p>
```

---

So as you can see, I need to get the first two sentences and put them in the first `<p>` tag.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If getSectionCopy() returns a String, I'm pretty sure you can do something like:

```
#set ($splitString = $page.getSectionCopy().split("\\.")) ## split takes regex - split on period.
<p>
    $splitString[0].trim().  $splitString[1].trim().
</p>
<p>
    #foreach ($sentence in $splitString)
        ## $velocityCount built in variable to count for index.  1 based, not 0 based.
        #if ($velocityCount > 2) 
            $sentence.trim().&nbsp;
        #end
    #end
</p>
```

Haven't tested the code.

Also, here is a related post that might help: [Using velocity split() to split a string into an array doesnt seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21288687/using-velocity-split-to-split-a-string-into-an-array-doesnt-seem-to-work)

Comment: Thanks jrahhali, I have a split on the go now. The only thing I need now is to have a loop as I dont know how many sentences will be each time. My only constant is the first two sentences will be in the first <P> tag.

Comment: updated the code with a for loop.  Hopefully $velocityCount works for you.

Comment: apprently, if you are using velocity 1.7+, there is a $foreach.index (zero based) and a $foreach.count (one based).  You can try these out also, if you want.  Reference here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847432/how-to-get-a-zero-based-count-in-a-velocity-foreach-loop